# HTML attribute encoding 

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, encoding, razor, xss

I have an .cshtml page with the following HTML in it:

```
<div class="content rowBody">
       <span class="rowText" title="@description">                           
              @description                           
       </span>
</div>
```

If the value of @description is: `<img src=x onerror=alert(/XSS/.source)>`
I see it showing up just like this in the *title* attribute and therefore executing, while the one in between the span tag appears to be encoded and does not trigger the alert box.

My assumption was that the Razor engine view attempts to encode anything preceded by the @. Does this not apply to HTML attributes?

Generated source:

```
<div style="margin-left: 31px;" class="content rowBody unselectable" unselectable="on">
                        <span class="rowText unselectable" title="<img src=x onerror=alert(/XSS/.source)>" unselectable="on">                           
                            &lt;img src=x onerror=alert(/XSS/.source)&gt;                           
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please show us the generated source.  That should not happen.

Comment: This does look like it's incorrect. I'm a bit at a loss as to why though. Razor should be encoding both cases identically. I'll try to get a repro when I can. If you can narrow down a fairly straightforward sample please send it to anurse AT microsoft DOT com and I'll look in to it. Don't hesitate to contact me there regardless of if you can narrow down a sample.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're seeing here is different encoding based on the context. The required output encoding for HTML tags is different to HTML attributes as it is different for JavaScript and different again for CSS.

Having said that, I couldn't reproduce this behaviour with a clean MVC4 project. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using MVC3. I'm guessing the default encoding might not apply to the attributes? Otherwise, it might have something to do with the way I got the data in... I was trying to bypass the .net ValidateRequest so the value for @description was actually added to the DB via a file upload tool within the app. (I have yet to review that code)